# How can I activate a rotate on a click instead of hover is css

Tags: html, css

I am very new at this. I have three boxes with information on both sides.  They currently `rotate` on `hover` but I would like them to only `rotate` on `click`.  How do I accomplish this?

```css
.flip3D {
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.flip3D>.front {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px) rotateY( 0deg);
  transform: perspective( 600px) rotateY( 0deg);
  background: #FC0;
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear 0s;
  transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
}

.flip3D>.back {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px) rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: perspective( 600px) rotateY( 180deg);
  background: #80BFFF;
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear 0s;
  transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
}

.flip3D:hover>.front {
  -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px) rotateY( -180deg);
  transform: perspective( 600px) rotateY( -180deg);
}

.flip3D:hover>.back {
  -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px) rotateY( 0deg);
  transform: perspective( 600px) rotateY( 0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip3D">
  <div class="back">Box 1 - Back</div>
  <div class="front">Box 1 - Front</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This would require a javascript click event listener. You will also need to update your CSS to change with the newly created class (`.active`) instead of on `:hover`.

```js
var box = document.querySelector('.flip3D');

box.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (box.classList.contains('active')) {
    box.classList.remove('active');
  } else {
    box.classList.add('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.flip3D {
  width:240px;
  height:200px;
  margin:10px;
  float:left;
}

.flip3D .front{
 position:absolute;
 -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
 transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
 background:#FC0; width:240px; height:200px; border-radius: 7px;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear 0s;
 transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
}

.flip3D .back{
 position:absolute;
 -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 180deg );
 transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 180deg );
 background: #80BFFF; width:240px; height:200px; border-radius: 7px;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear 0s;
 transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
}

.flip3D.active .front{
 -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -180deg );
 transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -180deg );
}
.flip3D.active .back{
 -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
 transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
}
```

```html
<div class="flip3D">
  <div class="back">Box 1 - Back</div>
  <div class="front">Box 1 - Front</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:active` pseudo class. However, `active` is triggered on `mousedown` and untriggered on `mouseup`. Not sure this fits your requirements. If not, you may need to resort to a `js` solution with `event handlers`.

```css
.flip3D {
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.flip3D>.front {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px) rotateY( 0deg);
  transform: perspective( 600px) rotateY( 0deg);
  background: #FC0;
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear 0s;
  transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
}

.flip3D>.back {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px) rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: perspective( 600px) rotateY( 180deg);
  background: #80BFFF;
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: -webkit-transform .5s linear 0s;
  transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
}

.flip3D:active>.front {
  -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px) rotateY( -180deg);
  transform: perspective( 600px) rotateY( -180deg);
}

.flip3D:active>.back {
  -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px) rotateY( 0deg);
  transform: perspective( 600px) rotateY( 0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip3D">
  <div class="back">Box 1 - Back</div>
  <div class="front">Box 1 - Front</div>
</div>
```